# How to implement search feature based on multiple parameters?

Tags: mysql, search, database-design, architecture

If I have a user table that is in relationship with other tables and I want to filter users based on the user table columns(let's say want to filter by age, name, first name, location, post title which is in a different table and referenced by user id, etc...).

Is it still a good idea to use MySQL if we filter the user based on a ton of parameters?

If so how?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you're going to have to whiteboard your design and do a pros/cons list with RDMS vs NoSQL.  There are tons of articles on the topic related to choosing a design based on the goals of your data.  With RDMS you can achieve your design but will have to keep in mind index structure plus any storage constraints with adding many indexes for searching.  With NoSQL you'll have to thoughtfully design your document structure and maybe even version it, because your data has the potential to be highly de-normalized, but at least all your search criteria will be in one place.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am convinced that MySQL is the best fit but I am curious about how big tech companies like Facebook do it? When we search for something we get a suggestion from posts, videos, images, users, etc... almost everything. For SQL database, do we have multiple SQL queries to fetch almost everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into GraphQL, learn what is it and the idea behind it.  GraphQL is similar the concept you're asking about, developed by Facebook, and can be tiered with RDMS database like MySQL.  Here is some documentation to get you started:  https://www.serverless.com/blog/graphql-api-mysql-postgres-aurora